# C++ cannot acces vector elements when vector is returned from other method

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following code, which iterates over the result of a vector of `pqxx::result` rows.

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<pqxx::result::tuple>>
  filteredRowsPtr = getFilteredAssignmentRowsPtr(unfilteredRows);

std::vector<pqxx::result::tuple> filteredRows = *filteredRowsPtr;

for(int i = 0; i < filteredRows.size(); i++)
{
  returnMap[occurenceStudentIdStr] = returnMap[occurenceStudentIdStr] + 1; 
    pqxx::result::tuple currRow = filteredRows[i];

    for(int j = 0; j < currRow.size(); j++)
    {
        std::cout << "j = " << currRow[j] << endl;        
    }
}
```

`filteredRowsPtr` is a `unique_ptr` to a `vector<pqxx::result::tuple>` which is produced by the following method:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<pqxx::result::tuple>> 
CompletedExcersisesPerStudent::getFilteredAssignmentRowsPtr(pqxx::result unfilteredRows)
{
    std::vector<pqxx::result::tuple> rowsFilteredOnGradePercentile = filter.getRowsWithValidGradePercentile(unfilteredRows);
    std::vector<pqxx::result::tuple> filteredRows = filter.getRowsWithValidAssignmentTimes(rowsFilteredOnGradePercentile);

    return std::make_unique<std::vector<pqxx::result::tuple>>(filteredRows);
}
```

The vector is filled (since calling `size()` on it returns a positive number) and I can iterate over it fine, but when I try to actually access the elements contained in the row using

```
currRow[j]
```

I get a segmentation fault.

However: When I replace the call to `getFilteredAssignmentsRowPtr()` with the following, thusly replacing the contents of that method:

```
std::vector<pqxx::result::tuple> rowsFilteredOnGradePercentile = filter.getRowsWithValidGradePercentile(unfilteredRows);
std::vector<pqxx::result::tuple> filteredRows = filter.getRowsWithValidAssignmentTimes(rowsFilteredOnGradePercentile);
```

The expected result is outputted without any segfaults.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you're returning a pointer to a local variable that goes out of scope. Can I ask why you need the pointer?

Comment: That `unique_ptr` is completely redundant.

Comment: I tried just returning the std::vector<pqxx::result::tuple>>; this did not work either, so I tried using the ptr.

Answer (score 1):

Your error appears not reproducible (as you failed to provide a Minimal Verifiable Complete Example), but your design is flawed anyway: don't use a s`td::unique_ptr<std::vector>`. `std::vector` already supports memory management, so you don't need to add that with a `unique_ptr`. IHMO, the correct design would be more like

```
std::vector<pqxx::result::tuple>
getFilteredAssignmentRowsPtr(pqxx::result unfilteredRows)
{
  return filter.getRowsWithValidAssignmentTimes(
         filter.getRowsWithValidGradePercentile(unfilteredRows));
} 

auto filteredRows = getFilteredAssignmentRowsPtr(unfilteredRows);

for(int i = 0; i < filteredRows.size(); i++)
{
  returnMap[occurenceStudentIdStr] = returnMap[occurenceStudentIdStr] + 1; 
  auto currRow = filteredRows[i];

  for(int j = 0; j < currRow.size(); j++)
  {
     std::cout << "j = " << currRow[j] << endl;        
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by changing `getFilteredAssignmentRows` to return a vector instead of a unique ptr like you suggested, as well as passing a reference to a `pqxx::result` to `getFilteredAssignmentRows` like so:

```
std::vector<pqxx::result::tuple> CompletedExcersisesPerStudent::getFilteredAssignmentRowsPtr(pqxx::result& unfilteredRows)
{
    std::vector<pqxx::result::tuple> rowsFilteredOnGradePercentile = filter.getRowsWithValidGradePercentile(unfilteredRows);
    return filter.getRowsWithValidAssignmentTimes(rowsFilteredOnGradePercentile);
}
```

This works since `filter.getRowsWithValidGradePercentile` is defined to take a reference to `pqxx::result` instead of a `pqxx::result` itself.

I must have accidentaly mis-read this.

Thanks a lot all the same!